# Assign item to list if CONTAINS

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, contains

I have a list

```
public List<OrderLineItemQuestionPrice> QuestionPriceList { get; set; }

public class OrderLineItemQuestionPrice
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public Price Price { get; set; }
    public string QuestionCode { get; set; }
}
```

I have another list

```
List<OrderLineItemQuestionPrice> promotionItem;
```

and I want to assign items of `QuestionPriceList` to `promotionItem` if `QuestionCode` contains 'Promotion'.

```
List<OrderLineItemQuestionPrice> promotionItem = orderLineItemList.QuestionPriceList.Where(p=>p.QuestionCode.Contains("Promotion"))
```

Comment: can you add class definition of OrderLineItemQuestionPrice?

Comment: You need an AddRange : promotionItem.AddRange(QuestionPriceList);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem which I can see is that you don't calling `ToList();` at the end. Also if you don't want to check for exact string `Promotion` you should call `ToLower()`

```
List<OrderLineItemQuestionPrice> promotionItem = 
                                    orderLineItemList.QuestionPriceList
                                   .Where(p=>p.QuestionCode.ToLower().Contains("Promotion".ToLower()))
                                   .ToList()
```

Comment: `"Promotion".ToLower()`?

Comment: @AntP yes if he has in his QuestionCode: I deserve a promotion. Contains("Promotion") will not found it, but Contains("Promotion".ToLower()) will find it.

Comment: `"Promotion".ToLower() == "promotion"` :)